# Not able to login with Facebook using django-allauth

Tags: django, facebook, nginx, django-allauth

Previously I was working on my Django app on a local server and all my settings work with django-allauth (I was using `manage.py runserver` rather than nginx + gunicorn for staging/production)

Now, I'm implementing django-allauth to my staging website, but I can't make it work on my staging server (Note: In this example I've replaced my domain name to `mydomain.com`).

Basically after I clicked the link to login with Facebook at http://staging.mydomain.com/accounts/login/, it redirects to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&state=YXdAxg2WiIBo&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.mydomain.com%2Faccounts%2Ffacebook%2Flogin%2Fcallback%2F&client_id=1600059933550804&scope=email&auth_type=reauthenticate and I get the following errors:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

Here are my setting files:

**nginx conf file**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name staging.mydomain.me;

    location /static {
            alias /home/myusername/sites/staging.mydomain.me/static;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/staging.mydomain.me.socket;
    }
}
```

**settings.py**

```
...

SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
    }
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'users.adapters.AccountAdapter'
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'users.forms.UserApplicationForm'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True

...
```

**Settings in Facebook app**

[image: Facebook settings]

**Settings in Sites [http://staging.mydomain.com/admin/sites/site/1/]**

[image: Django Sites settings]

**Settings in Social application [http://staging.mydomain.com/admin/socialaccount/socialapp/2/]**

[image: Django-allauth social app settings]

Answer (score 0):

Try one of theese 2 things:

1. create a test app for your facebook app, and set the staging.mydomain.com domain for it, configure a brand new social app (allauth) with the new api key and secret (for your new test app), a new django site, and so on...
2. change your facebook app settings to have staging.mydomain.com as its app domain.

I think both solutions will work, but I prefer the first one, as your staging app perfectly fits in definition of 'test app' and therefore, I think is a more elegant solution.

Hope this helps you.